# Searching for multiple sub-strings within a single parent-string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been searching all day for a similar question to mine.  Many questions come close, but my questions is a bit different:

I have a list of last names in Column A.  In Cell B1, I have someone's full name, first and last separated by only a space (no comma or punctuation).

How can I identify whether or not any of the last names from my list in column A can be found within Cell B1.

I know how to find a single sub-string within a range of cells, but this is the opposite,  searching for any one of several sub-strings within a single cell of text.  For example:

If Column A has "Smith", "Johnson", and "Baker" in cells A1, A2, and A3 respectively, and Cell B1 has "Joe Johnson" in it, then C1 should say "true" or have a 1 in it.  If, on the other hand, Cell B1 has the word "Billy Bob" in it, then C1 should say "false" or have a 0 in it.

hope that is clear, Much gratitude for any and all help.

Comment: Can you provide an image of your example? I found it a little confusing to answer. I think I understand but want to be sure before I post an answer.

Comment: apparently, I cannot add an image unless I have more reputation.  Sorry.  I think my example is simplified enough to easily replicate.  Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to extract the last name from cell B1

`MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2)+1,99)`

Then you can use that result to perform a Match() on column A:

`=MATCH(MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,99),A:A,0)`  (in C1 of the screenshot)

This will return the row number of the found name. If a name is not found, the cell contains #N/A. To avoid that, you can use IsNumber to return TRUE/FALSE or IfError to return blank  cells for errors.

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,99),A:A,0))` ( in D1)

`=IFERROR(MATCH(MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,99),A:A,0),"")` (in E1)

Formulas in the screenshot have been copied down to row 2.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I see the process.  Thanks for your help.